# Differences in first-order Polygon Contiguity in ArcGIS - Contiguity Edges Corners (CEC) vs. Contiguity Edges Only (CEO)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-statistics, clustering, spatial-cluster

I am working on spatial autocorrelation, and using the spatial modeling relationship methods available in ArcMap.

In ArcMap, there are the following methods for polygon contiguity:

Contiguity Edges Only (CEO), which is using only coincident boundaries in order to create a spatial relationship (rooks) while Contiguity Edges Corners (CEC) uses coincident edges and corners of the polygon (queens). Link follows: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/modeling-spatial-relationships.htm

Now, I'm trying to figure out how exactly these methods are being used, and the pros/cons of each. I've been trying to look up the algorithms and spatial statistics related to these methods, unfortunately, to no avail. My guess is also that the Contiguity Edges Corners case would be much more computationally intensive, since it needs to explore more cases. Also, I am not quite sure how to interpret any spatial statistics generated from these 2 methods, and how to compare and contrast them in why different clusters may be highlighted (sometimes drastically differently) in ArcMap.

How does ArcMap (ArcGIS Desktop) implement this?

Another factor is weighting (by inverse distance, inverse distance squared, custom weight matrices, etc.) but I would like to save this for another time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It most likely uses graph theory. For example there are 2 groups if graph edges are shared boundaries only:

[image]

Links computed using Polygon to line.

There is just one group, if both corners and shared boundary are edges of graph:

[image]

Links computed using Polygon Neighbours.